# Which piece of software touches network configuration files of a VM in a vagrant-libvirt setup with kvm/qemu?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, vagrant, systemd-networkd

Which element in a vagrant-libvirt-qemu/kvm-chain is responsible to actually configure the VM? Like editing the network configuration files. Wouldn't that totally depend on the details of the OS of the VM?

*As an example,* I got the following lines in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.box = "archlinux/archlinux"
config.vm.network :private_network, :libvirt__network_name => "default", :mac => "52:54:00:00:00:1f", :ip => "192.168.30.7"
```

...and the VM ends up with dhcpcd (the client daemon) on all interfaces while systemd's `networkctl` shows that it manages all interfaces itself (one with static configuration, clearly conflicting with the dhcpcd). -- Only one of them should be in charge of any interface...

**So what entity dropped files in `/etc/systemd/network`? How was that entity so sure that systemd is being used in that VM anyway? Is that entity (which turns the knobs of the VM configuration) documented somewhere with those details?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `vagrant` itself. See the source [plugins/guests/arch/cap/configure_networks.rb#L57](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/d8fdc500b76c840cdeaa69869d0c000530b036b3/plugins/guests/arch/cap/configure_networks.rb#L57)